# Ruby - How to get the name of a file with open-uri?

Tags: ruby, http, url, uri, open-uri

I want to download a music file by this way:

```
require 'open-uri'

source_url = "http://soundcloud.com/stereo-foo/cohete-amigo/download"

attachment_file = "test.wav"

open(attachment_file, "wb") do |file|  
  file.print open(source_url).read
end
```

In that example I want to change "Test.wav" to the real file name (like for example JDownloader program does).

**EDIT**: I don't mean the temporal file, I mean the stored file in the web like Jdownloader gets: "Cohete Amigo - Stereo Foo.wav"

Thankyou for read

UPDATE:

I've tried this  to store the name:

```
attachment_file = File.basename(open(source_url))
```

I think that has no sense but i don't know the way to do it, sorry.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The filename is stored in the header field named `Content-Disposition`. However decoding this field can be a little bit tricky. See some discussion here for example:

[How to encode the filename parameter of Content-Disposition header in HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http)

For `open-uri` you can access all the header fields through the [`meta`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI/Meta.html) accessor of the returned `File` class:

```
f = open('http://soundcloud.com/stereo-foo/cohete-amigo/download')
f.meta['content-disposition']
=> "attachment;filename=\"Stereo Foo - Cohete Amigo.wav\""
```

So in order to decode something like that you could do this:

```
cd = f.meta['content-disposition'].
filename = cd.match(/filename=(\"?)(.+)\1/)[2]
=> "Stereo Foo - Cohete Amigo.wav"
```

It works for your particular case, and it also works if the quotes `"` are not present. But in the more complex content-disposition cases like UTF-8 filenames you could get into a little trouble. Not sure how often UTF-8 is used though, and if even soundcloud ever uses UTF-8. So maybe you don't need to worry about that (not confirmed nor tested).

You could also use a more advanced web-crawling framework like [`Mechanize`](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/File.html), and trust it to do the decoding for you:

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
file = agent.get('http://soundcloud.com/stereo-foo/cohete-amigo/download')
file.filename
=> "Stereo_Foo_-_Cohete_Amigo.wav"
```

Comment: thanks, do you know if I can retreive the filesize too and without waiting to get all the mb of the file?

Comment: Look inside the Content-length header.

Answer (score 6):

`File.basename(open(source_url))` won't work because `open(source_url)` returns an I/O handle of some sort, not a string like `File.basename` expects.

```
File.basename(source_url)
```

would have a better chance of working, unless the URL is using some `path/to/service/with/parameters/in/line/like/this` type encoding.

Ruby's URI library has useful tools to help here though. Something like:

```
File.basename(URI.parse(source_url).path)
```

would be a starting point. For instance:

```
require 'uri'

File.basename(URI.parse('http://www.example.com/path/to/file/index.html').path
# => "index.html"
```

and:

```
File.basename(URI.parse('http://www.example.com/path/to/file/index.html?foo=bar').path)
# => "index.html"
```

---

> do you know if I can retreive the filesize too and how?

A great way to test HTTP stuff locally, is to run [`gem server`](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/18) from the command-line, and let gems fire up a little web server for its documentation:

```
require 'open-uri'

html_doc = open('http://0.0.0.0:8808/') do |io|
  puts io.size
  io.read
end

puts html_doc.size

# => 114350
# => 114350
```

When you use a block with OpenURI's [`open`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI/OpenRead.html#method-i-open) command, it gives you access to a lot of information about the connection in the block variable, which is an instance of the [`Tempfile`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html) class. So, you can find out the size of the incoming file using `size`.

That's OK for small files, but if you're pulling in a big file you might want to investigate using Net::HTTP to send a [`head`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-head) request, which *might* include the size. I say *might*, because sometimes the server doesn't know how much will be returned, in the case of dynamic content, or content being returned by a CGI or sub-service that doesn't bother to say.

The advantage to using a "head" request is the server doesn't return the entire content, just the headers. So, in the past, I've prefaced a request using `head`, to see if I could get the data I needed. If not, I'd be forced to pull in the full response using a normal `get`.

Comment: thanks, do you know if I can retreive the filesize too and how?

Comment: Filesize is harder. It's often returned in the HTTP headers returned from the server, and can be accessed via Net::HTTP's methods. Some of them are available in OpenURI's headers if you use a block with `open`. The problem is, not all requests result in a Content-Length header because the server doesn't know how much is coming back. That's especially true for dynamic content being generated by a CGI of some sort.

Comment: I'll add a sample for OpenURI.